# Show Blob content into OleContainer Delphi

Tags: delphi, devexpress, media, ole

Using XE8.
Devex TcxGrid whith a column representing blob data with PopupEditProperties and PopupControl = a TOleContainer control.
That column represents a database field (BlobType) for various data types (images, pdf, word, excel, mpg, avi, mp3, ppt, etc.)

When OnInitPopup event from PopupEditProperties fires I want do this:

```
var
  MS: TMemoryStream;
  OC: TOleContainer;
begin
  if not Query1.FieldByName('data').isNull then begin
    OC := TcxPopupEditProperties(cxGrid1DBTableView1Data.Properties).PopupControl as TOleContainer; 
    //Size of Container
    with OC do begin
      Parent := TcxPopupEdit(Sender).PopupWindow;
      Left := 5;
      Top := 5;
      Width := cxGrid1DBTableView1.Controller.FocusedColumn.Width;
      Height := 300;
    end;
    MS := TMemoryStream.Create;
    try
      TBlobField(Query1.FieldByName('data')).SaveToStream(MS);
    // I Want show the content with appropiate application
      OC.LoadFromStream(MS); // here crashes
    finally
      MS.Free; 
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Invalid stream format message is raised.
Which is the best issue for do this?

Answer (score 4):

`TOleContainer` uses its own format with `LoadFromStream`/`SaveToStream`. I assume your DB blob holds the original file data. You need to save `TMemoryStream` to a temp file and then call `CreateObjectFromFile`.

<strike>Another option is to use this solution: [Load a TOleContainer from a stream which contains a file image, without using CreateObjectFromFile](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/21821816/Load-a-TOleContainer-from-a-stream-which-contains-a-file-image-without-using-CreateObjectFromFile.html#comments) (I would personally hack the needed private members and wrote a stand alone procedure, but it would be version depended).</strike>

Apparently the above "solution" which I *assumed* was correct does not work and fails with `"%1 already exists"` EOleSysError exception as you mentioned in your comments.

So, AFAIK only way is to use a temp file with a proper extension. The extension is needed to determine which OLE server application will handle the file. each of those extensions are registered on your machine in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`.  IMO,  You *must* save the file type in the DB. How would Your application later knows which type it is? Only way would be to examine the stream/blob *signature* (which could be not 100% accurate).

Comment: I unknown the file type, anything must be added: videos, docs, xls, pdfs, images opening from a file or pasting from clipboard ... 
I tested "LoadAsDocument" as example says, but an EOleSysError raises "%1 already exists" ... :(

Comment: ` OleCheck(StgOpenStorageOnILockBytes(FLockBytes, nil, STGM_READWRITE or
      STGM_SHARE_EXCLUSIVE, nil, 0, FStorage));`
Here raises

Comment: You are correct. I assumed the solution is accurate without testing it.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot load raw file format into TOleContainer directly. This stream must be in special OLE format. This is why you got error "Invalid stream format".

As workaround, you can save your BLOB into temporary file with appropriate file extension. For example: c:\temp\image.gif
And than load it into TOleContainer as follow:

```
OC.CreateObjectFromFile('c:\temp\image.gif', false);
```

Edit: If you don't know actual file format, you can detect it! For example you can try Marco Pontello's TrID library. So first detect file format and save it to temp folder and than load to OC.